# Error in translateR package

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a text from French to English using `translate` function in `translateR` package. I am using MS translator. Could anybody help me to solve this? I am new to R language and don't have much expertise into this.

This code:

```
text1 <- "joyeux Noël"  
translate(content.vec=text1, microsoft.client.id='xxxxxx', 
          microsoft.client.sec‌ret = 'ZlZ39GooG6w1oiDlUgPcUQXGq7B+jCfchdrL9h0ebz8=',
          source.lang = 'fr', target.lang = '‌​en')
```

Throws:

> Error in fromJSON(postForm("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13",  : 
>     error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     Failed to connect to datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Could you provide an example producing this error? But this looks like a firewall issue.

Comment: text1
[1] "joyeux Noël" translate(content.vec=text1[1],microsoft.client.id='xxxxxx',microsoft.client.secret='ZlZ39GooG6w1oiDlUgPcUQXGq7B+jCfchdrL9h0ebz8=',source.lang='fr',target.lang='en')

Comment: Please, edit your question body to provide examples.