# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Could not resolve host: datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net

Tags: r

> I am trying to convert a text from French to English using translate
>   function in translateR package. I am using MS translator. Could
>   anybody help me to solve this? I am new to R language and don't have
>   much expertise into this.
>
> This code:

```
library(translateR)
res <- translate(content.vec = c("Hello world.", "This is a test."), 
                 microsoft.client.id = "143bc77b-80fd-4a71-ae9d-7e37373fd84c", 
                 microsoft.client.secret = "biAW515)[jpbulULGTK11$+", 
                 source.lang = "en", 
                 target.lang = "de")
res
```

Throws error:

> ```
> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>   Could not resolve host: datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net
> In addition: Warning message:
> The content appears to be in MIDDLE_FRISIAN. However, the language code you provided suggests that
> the text is in ENGLISH. If you entered the wrong language code, stop the process. Otherwise,
> translateR will treat the text as ENGLISH.
> ```

Comment: This has already been asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322479/error-in-translater-package

Comment: Just an alert, I don't know this package and idk if this is actually "secret" but you are displaying your microsoft.client.id and secret for everyone here. Is that ok?

Comment: I am just trying the package and the coding. Not that much alert for me -tk3

Comment: @DavidPell but the exact answer is not there and it's a lil' different.